# about before function in typeinfo

Tags: c++

I am reading modern C++ design. Following is the text snippet taken from typeinfo description.

> The before member function introduces
>   an ordering relationship for type_info
>   objects. Using type_info::before, you
>   can perform indexing on type_info
>   objects.
>
> If you want to sort type_info objects, again you must actually store
>   pointers to type_info, and this time
>   you must use the before member
>   function. Consequently, if you want to
>   use STL's ordered containers with
>   type_info, you must write a little
>   functor and deal with pointers.

In above description, what is meant by indexing on type_info objects and how can we achieve this using "before" function.

Also another question is what does author mean if we want to use STL containers with type_info, we must write a little functor and deal with pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: He meant that if you want to use C++ Standard containers with `type_info`, then you must write a little functor and deal with pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Indexing" here means using it as the key in an ordered container, such as `std::set` or `std::map`. These require a comparison functor to order the keys. You'll also need to use pointers to `type_info`, rather than the objects themselves, since they are not copyable. It could be achieved like this:

```
struct type_info_before
{
    bool operator()(std::type_info const * a, std::type_info const * b)
    {
        return a->before(*b);
    }
};

typedef std::set<std::type_info const *, type_info_before> type_info_set;
```

Or, as is described in the book, you could wrap the pointer in a little class and overload the comparison operators for that.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you don't know if you get the same type_info object each time or if there are several objects referring to the same type. Therefore you cannot just compare the type_ info objects themselves.

The before() function must sort this out, in an implementation specific way, and return a proper ordering.

Answer (score 0):

> what does author mean if we want to
>   use STL containers with type_info, we
>   must write a little functor and deal
>   with pointers.

That part means when using STL ordered containers, you have to tell the container how to sort the elements it contains, and for that you've to write a functor that would use `type_info::before` internally to do the comparison between `type_info` *pointers*.

Ordered container requires sorting, sorting requires comparison, comparison requires you to write a  *comparer* that is either a function or functor. Simple!